# Scripts can run on terminal but not when using PHP

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I am trying to run a script that does "apt-get install" on a webserver through PHP but cant seem to get it to work. If I were to run the script locally on the terminal using:

> sudo /var/www/html/dl.sh

It works. But after using this code...

**forcedl.php:**

```
 <?php
      if ($_GET['run']){
        $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/dl.sh");
        echo "<pre>$output\n</pre>";
      }
    ?>

<a href=?run=true>Click Here</a>
```

**dl.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install slowhttptest
```

and after clicking on CLICK HERE (If commands in dl.sh were changed to ifconfig, it works) on another machine, nothing happens on the server that the script is supposed to run on.

If I remember correctly, I have installed PHP and Apache2. I don't know if anything else is required to make this work.

Requested command:

> ls -lZ /var/www/html/dl.sh

Output is:

> rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 188 Jan 2 21:58 /var/www/html/dl.sh

Edit #2:

I solved the issue by adding WWW-DATA in sudoers and editing my PHP.

**forcedl.php:**

```
 <?php
      if ($_GET['run']){
        $output = shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/dl.sh");
        echo "<pre>$output\n</pre>";
      }
    ?>

<a href=?run=true>Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is (thankfully!) not running as the `root` user, so it does not have privileges to run `apt install`.  The `suid` bit is ignored on shell scripts, so setting that bit on your shell script is not a solution, either.

If you *really really* want to give PHP the privileges to run `apt-get` as the `root` user (and please, think *really* hard about this), you can add an entry to `sudoers` to allow it to do so, but your command will have to be `sudo apt-get [...]`.

Running a script through a web based front-end via a `sudo` grant is ill-advised, because if somebody somehow figures out a way to edit that file, now they can do whatever they want to do on your system as the superuser by having PHP do it for them.

Comment: probably also need to add `!RequireTTY` to that sudo config.  And yeah, allowing a webserver to run anything via `sudo` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Hm.. So to allow it, I will just have to add an entry to 'sudoers' and ensure my command has 'sudo' in it? 
Since this is just a test to simulate that an attacker has put in a script into the webserver, my professor has given an OK for any method used. He just told me to get it to work haha.

Comment: @TimKennedy, Able to elaborate more on that?

Comment: @Ｓｙｕｕバカ sudo usually requires a TTY because it's default behavior is to attempt interactive authentication.  When you do something like allow a webserver to run a script non-interactively, you would need to configure sudo appropriately, by adding `NOPASSWD` and `!RequireTTY` to the appropriate place(s) in the `sudoers` file.  It's hard to be more specific because there are a myriad of ways to add those options.